# Bootstrap HTML Table Export using TableExport.js not working

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using TableExport.js plugin - https://tableexport.v3.travismclarke.com/ to incorporate Bootstrap HTML table export onto my site.

I followed all steps to include jquery FileSaver, tableExport javascripts and css.

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="../vendor/TableExport/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<!-- TableExport JavaScript -->
<script src="../vendor/TableExport/js/tableexport.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/TableExport/js/tableexport.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
<script src="../vendor/datatables/jstest/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```

Belwo is how I call tableExport function:

```
<caption class="btn-toolbar bottom tableexport-caption">
                    <button tableexport-id="c203fc6-xlsx" class="btn btn-default xlsx" onClick="$("#dataTables-example").tableExport();">Export to xlsx</button>
                    <button tableexport-id="759d678-xls" class="btn btn-default xls" onClick="$("#dataTables-example").tableExport();">Export to xls</button>
                    <button tableexport-id="87e8a31-csv" class="btn btn-default csv" onClick="$("#dataTables-example").tableExport();">Export to csv</button>
                    <button tableexport-id="78cbc47-txt" class="btn btn-default txt" onClick="$("#dataTables-example").tableExport();">Export to txt</button>
                    </caption>
```

But, I am getting error when I click on any of the buttons:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input here at <button tableexport-id="78cbc47-txt" class="btn btn-default txt" onClick="$("#dataTables-example").tableExport();">Export to txt</button>
```

[image]

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with the double quotes inside onClick

```
<button tableexport-id="78cbc47-txt" class="btn btn-default txt" onClick="$('#dataTables-example').tableExport();">Export to txt</button>
```

Comment: yes tried that already. everytime i click on button now, I get below error:

tableexport.min.js:formatted:367 Uncaught TypeError: n is not a function
    at Object.export2file (tableexport.min.js:formatted:367)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (tableexport.min.js:formatted:212)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:formatted:2117)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.js:formatted:1996)

Comment: You included tableexport.js & tableexport.min.js can you remove one them and try?

Comment: removed tableexport.min.js and I get below error:

tableexport.js:584 Uncaught TypeError: saveAs is not a function
    at Object.export2file (tableexport.js:584)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (tableexport.js:319)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)

Comment: Looks like it is an issue with FileSaver.js and as per doc's the order of files in html script tags is first FileSaver.js and then tableexport.js can you make the change and try?

Comment: yes that did work. but now seeing strange issue - when i click first time on any of the button it creates duplicate set of same buttons. and when I click on any of the duplicate buttons it saves the file xls/csv/txt. Also, it pulls in only first page rows instead of entire result set from the scrollable HTML pages. any idea why?

Other thing is excel file doesnt pull in data instead i see [object Object] on all columns.

Comment: when i click on any buttons they are rendered again on the HTML Table. I am seeing below error on chrome console:

[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 86ms

Comment: try defaulting `exportButtons` to false

Comment: Hi @Venu Duggireddy, I've given up on this as going no where with it. Instead using https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/export as it serves the purpose for me. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

I've given up on this as going no where with it. Instead using github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/… as it serves the purpose for me. Thanks for your help and time.